# In Smarty, how can I specify a default template to display?

Tags: php, templates, smarty

To display a template all it takes is:

```
$smarty->display('base_layout.tpl');
```

In my project I will always be using the same template but changing the variables. Is there a config value that I can set up in a config file so that I can just do:

```
$smarty->display();
```

and have that always call `filename.tpl`?

Comment: if you don't know, should you be using smarty?

Comment: @thang, You don't have to know everything about something before using it. If that was the case nobody could do anything. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite `smarty->display()` function to handle its parameters.

Comment: That's genius, thanks. Here is my code for it: `class Smarty2 extends Smarty { function display($template = 'base_layout.tpl', $cache_id = null, $compile_id = null, $parent = null){ parent::display($template, $cache_id, $compile_id, $parent); } }`